Is there a resource for calculating the total lifespan of electronic components in smartphones and tablets?
I'm interested in how long it takes for the components in smartphones and tablet devices to materially break down, destabilise, dissolve, etc. For example, what's the speculative half life of the radioactive materials in touchscreens? Is anyone here familiar with any sort of component lifespan calculator that doesn't just look at the usable lifespan of a smartphone (e.g. 2-5 years) and instead looks at the 'deep-time' life of the hardware?

The problem is about definition. What do you mean for dissolve? Where do you stop the clock? Quarz is natural (so glass). Metal: you may find piece of metal in nature, etc. Plastic is the most problematic (I think). And I doubt there is radioactive material in phones (and not in touchscreen): why? In short: if you remove plastic and you crash a phone in small pieces, you have sand (a special mix, but nothing you will not find in sand somewhere on Earth)

Look further back, at electronics from the 70s and up - when plastics and circuit boards started to appear. The current biggest issue with old electronics is probably the batteries and capacitors, followed by any glues, seals and other connection points holding it together/airtight. E.g. Screens on Gameboys & laptops from the 80s/90s are starting to delaminate now after 30 years, causing dead spots (vertical bars, etc). Leaky capacitors have been destroying traces on boards for decades. I agree with Giacomo - at what point do you draw the line?
